# alert box not popping out when using requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am new to require js and have been looking online for tutorials but do not really understand them.

I have placed all my jquery and require js in the same folder as my html file.

**Test.html**

```
<html>
   <head>
    <script data-main = "main" src = "require.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>

   </head>
   <body> testing </body> 
</html>
```

**Main.js (require main file)**

```
    requirejs.config(
    { 
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery-2.1.3.min'
        }
    });

    require(
    ['test']
        function(test){
    test.msg();
    }
    );
```

**test.js**

```
define('alerts', ['jquery']
   function($){
    var msg = function(){ 
       $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('i am just learning');
    });
    };

    return {msg:msg};

});
```

am i doing something wrongly?

the error in the debugger showed that msg was an undefined reference. I have somewhat tried to follow tutorials and tried to change parts of it to explore

Comment: The code you show in your question won't execute, and this is quite independent from RequireJS.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define a **baseUrl** in the require config to be referenced by **paths**
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly named your module `alerts` but requested it via `require('test')...`. You're not required to name your modules, it's better not to do this and let RequireJS add names behind the scenes.